# ¿Como chequear unos input segun el valor que venga un json, jquery?

Tags: jquery, json

Buen día, actualmente genero un listado de cupones dinamicamente de la siguiente forma:

```
var cupones_bienvenida = $('.cupones_bienvenida');
                        var tipoCupon ='';

                        $.each(response.data, function (i) {
                            if (response.data[i].Sub_Tipo == 1){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 1";
                            }
                            else if(response.data[i].Sub_Tipo == 2){
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 2";
                            }
                            else{
                                tipoCupon = "Cupón 3";
                            }


                              $('<tr class="cupones"/>')
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('nuevo-td td-cuponera-costarica')
                                        .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content').text(response.data[i].Nombre)))
                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td').append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text(tipoCupon))
                                        .append($('<p class="td-parrafor-cupcostarica"/>').text("Descuento: "+response.data[i].Descuento)))


                                    .append('<div class="cod_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Identificador + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="descuento_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Descuento + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="tipo_cupon" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Tipo_cupon + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="sub_tipo" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Sub_Tipo + '</div>')
                                    .append('<div class="vencimiento" style="display:none">' + response.data[i].Fecha_vence + '</div>')

                                    .append($('<td/>').addClass('label-cell nuevo-td')
                                                .append($('<label/>').addClass('label-checkbox item-content')
                                                            .append('<input type="checkbox" name="cupon_check" class="cupon_check" value="' + response.data[i].Identificador + '"/>')
                                                            .append($('<span/>').addClass('item-media').append('<i class="icon icon-form-checkbox"></i>'))))
                                    .appendTo(cupones_bienvenida);
                             if (cantidad_llaves === 0) {
                                $('.cupon_check').prop('disabled', true)
                            }

                            });

$('.cupones_bienvenida').on('click','.cupon_check', function(e){
        //Aca obtengo los valores del listado dinamico
    });
```

Resulta que al seleccionar los checkbox

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todo me trabaja bien, el detalle surge cuando realizo un cambio de vista, 
por ejemplo me encuentro en 'pagina/cupones.html' y luego al irme a otra vista como 'pagina/principal.html', al regresar a cupones.html la informacion seleccionada se ha borrado.

Entonces pretendo generar un json con la informacion del listado de cupones.
Pero tengo la duda como debe ir estructurado este json y luego como volver a cargar este json a la lista para que la información no se vea afectada, es decir solo se guarde temporalmente.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la propiedad [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) para almacenar el valor de tus inputs y setearlos cada vez que cargas tu html.

De esta forma, para guardar el valor de tus checksbox:

```
function guardar(){
    var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
    var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
    //...
    if(checkbox1.checked) {
        localStorage.setItem('checkbox1', 1);
    }
    if(checkbox2.checked){
        localStorage.setItem('checkbox2', 1);
    }
    //...
}
```

para setearlos de nuevo en el HTML:

```
function leer(){    
    var checkbox1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1'));
    var checkbox2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox2'));

    if (checkbox1 == "1") {
        document.getElementById("checkbox1").setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
    if (checkbox2 == "1") {
        document.getElementById("checkbox2").setAttribute('checked','checked');
    }
}
```

Entonces, al momento de moverte entre vistas ejecutas `guardar()` para guardar el estado actual de los checkbox y `leer()` para setearlos cada vez que se carga un HTML. Puede quedar algo así:

```
<html>
<script>

function guardar(){
        var checkbox1 = document.getElementById('checkbox1');
        var checkbox2 = document.getElementById('checkbox2');
        //...
        if(checkbox1.checked) {
            localStorage.setItem('checkbox1', 1);
        }
        if(checkbox2.checked){
            localStorage.setItem('checkbox2', 1);
        }
        //...
    }
}
function leer(){    
        var checkbox1 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox1'));
        var checkbox2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('checkbox2'));

        if (checkbox1 == "1") {
            document.getElementById("checkbox1").setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
        if (checkbox2 == "1") {
            document.getElementById("checkbox2").setAttribute('checked','checked');
        }
    }
function pasarAOtroTab(){
    guardar();
    window.location.assign("otraPagina.html");
}

function destroy(){
location.reload();
localStorage.clear();
}

</script>

<body onload="leer();">

<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1">1e film van de dag</input>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2">1e film van de dag</input>
<button onclick="pasarAOtroTab();">Otro Tab</button>
<button onclick="destroy();">Limpiar localStorage</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Hay formas más directas de hacer este control, pero lo dejo lo más simple para que se entienda más rápido.